# LaTeX error when inserting code listing in LyX

Tags: beamer, lyx, presentations

I am currently making a presentation in LyX. After I have inserted some XML code in a code listing, I am getting this error:

```
Paragraph ended before \lst@next was complete.
Paragraph ended before \lst@next was complete.
LaTeX Error: \begin{lstlisting} on input line 228 ended by \end{beamer@framep
Missing } inserted.
Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.
```

What's the problem? Have I to escape some characters or something? I am pretty new to LyX.

EDIT:

Here is a little code snippet. Because I am working with LyX, the code is generated and looks a little bit confusing, I think. I hope you can read it.

```
\begin_layout BeginFrame
\lang english
Güte der Ergebnisse
\end_layout
\begin_layout Standard
\lang english
\begin_inset listings
inline false
status open
\begin_layout Plain Layout
<server> 
\end_layout
\begin_layout Plain Layout
<name>MyServer</name> 
\end_layout
\begin_layout Plain Layout
<version>1</version> 
\end_layout
\begin_layout Plain Layout
<functionality>0</functionality> 
\end_layout
\begin_layout Plain Layout
<platform>Win</platform> 
\end_layout
\begin_layout Plain Layout
</server> 
\end_layout
\begin_layout Plain Layout
</ddsml> 
\end_layout
\end_inset
\end_layout
\begin_layout EndFrame
\start_of_appendix
\end_layout
```

Comment: A minimal example would be nice. It looks like you're using beamer as well as listings? How are you using listings?

Comment: If any of the answers below solved your issue, would you consider accepting it by click the checkmark next to it?

Comment: oh, sorry. i missed that.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Perhaps this should rather be a comment on egregs answer, but it became a little long.

I searched a little, and there is a module for creating fragile frames, that can be found [in the LyX wiki](http://wiki.lyx.org/Layouts/Modules#toc9). I don't know how to install modules, but I guess that information can also be found in the LyX wiki.

An alternative is to use ERTs ([source](http://marc.info/?l=lyx-users&m=125957115114257&w=2)):

1. Instead of starting a new frame the LyX way, add a TeX code box, or ERT, by hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>, or choosing Insert --> TeX Code. In this box you write

   ```
   \begin{frame}[fragile]
   \frametitle{Title of the frame}
   ```
2. Add the listing.
3. Finally a second ERT with

   ```
   \end{frame}
   ```

Comment: \begin{frame}[fragile]{Title} works also.

Answer (score 11):

I don't know how to do this in LyX, but a frame containing "verbatim" material such as a `lstlisting` environment should be declared as `fragile`:

```
\begin{frame}[fragile]
...
\begin{lstlisting}
...
\end{lstlisting}

\end{frame}
```

Answer (score 5):

In LyX 2.1, you do not need to enter LaTeX code directly to achieve frames handling fragile elements correctly.

Just select the frame and press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> <kbd>3</kbd>.
The new field "Options" should appear where you enter `fragile`. Alternatively, right click on the Frame 'header', and select *Frame Options*.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Just wondering, is this new for LyX 2.1?

Comment: @TorbjørnT. yes (and I agree, that should be stated in the answer)

Comment: Also, I believe the shortcut is alt + a 3 (not 'g').

Answer (score 2):

use it this way:

*before* the frame insert with `Ctrl-L` for inserting LaTeX Code

```
\defverbatim\lst{%
\begin{lstlisting}
your xml code}
\end{lstlisting}
}
```

inside the frame place also with `Ctrl-L` the command `\lst` where the listing should appear.