# LaTeX getting "Missing } inserted" error

Tags: beamer, errors, verbatim

I'm getting "Missing } inserted" error, when compiling with `pdflatex` and I really don't understand why. This is occurring in a `beamer` `frame`. Maybe someone comes up with something useful.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
...
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{default}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{graphics}
...
\begin{frame}\frametitle{3\textonehalf. Generace}

    \begin{block}{3\textonehalf. Generace}
        \begin{itemize}
            \item OOP
        \end{itemize}
    \end{block}

    \begin{exampleblock}{Jazyky 3\textonehalf. generace}
        \begin{itemize}
            \item první Smalltalk
            \item C{}\verb!++!, Objective-C, Object Pascal, Java
            \item statické / dynamické
        \end{itemize}
    \end{exampleblock}

\end{frame}
...
```

I get the error on the last line.

Comment: Use `\begin{frame}[fragile]` when the frame contains verbatim bits.

Comment: that's it, thanx :-)

Comment: Although there is no need to use `verb` there `++` or if you want, `\texttt{++}` would work

Comment: Assuming egreg is right, you could avoid the problem by using [this method](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/4302/575) for typsetting `C++`.

Comment: I couldn't find a reference to the use of `fragile` frames in `beamer` when dealing with `verbatim`. Perhaps we should write an answer, @egreg?

Comment: @Werner There is http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36776/latex-error-when-inserting-code-listing-in-lyx, for example

Comment: @egreg -- your cited question does mention `fragile` but the question is tagged with `lyx` so on the surface, one might think it not relevant.  a pointer to section 3.13, "verbatim text", in the `beamer` manual might be more helpful.

Comment: @Werner -- the first example in section 3.13, "verbatim text" of the `beamer` manual starts with `\begin{frame}[fragile]`.  i didn't know about this either, so think an answer might be helpful here.  reopen?  (might benefit from restating the question a bit.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton: I've voted...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

the problem, as pointed out by egreg, is that you need to specify

```
\begin{frame}[fragile]
```

when including verbatim material in the frame.

this is documented in the `beamer` manual (`texdoc beamer`) in section 3.1.3, "verbatim text".  (it almost never hurts to check the manual, and the `beamer` manual is a good one.)