# pdflatexmk beamer missing { inserted

Tags: beamer, pdftex

I am usig two different systems to write my presentation. on linux I use `texmaker` and everything works fine. But when I move to mac and use `texshop`  I encounter the above error in the following part:

```
where $V \in \mathbb{R}_\textbf{+}^{m \times n}$ ,$W \in \mathbb{R}_\textbf{+}^{m \times k}$, $H \in \mathbb{R}_\textbf{+}^{k \times n}$ and $k <<min\{m,n\}$.
```

minimal example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

% \usepackage{beamerthemesplit} // Activate for custom appearance

\title{Example }
\date{\today}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Non-negative Matrix Factorization}

where $V \in \mathbb{R}_\textbf{+}^{m \times n}$ ,$W \in \mathbb{R}_\textbf{+}^{m \times k}$, $H \in \mathbb{R}_\textbf{+}^{k \times n}$ and $k <<min\{m,n\}$.
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

The way to fix it is to change `_\textbf{+}` to simple `_+`. the only related problem I could find was [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/114132/latex-getting-missing-inserted-error) post, but it didn't help

Comment: don't use `_\textbf{+}` that is unreliable, try `_{\textbf{+}}`, I'd use `\bm` from the `bm` package instead of `\textbf`

Comment: Plus, always, always provide a compilable minimal example such that others can try it out without having to guess what your preamble looks like.

Comment: @daleif I added the example.I tried us `bm`but it gives the same error. `_{\textbf{+}}` worked,thanks . why it is unreliable?

Comment: @daleif oh got it. it should be `_{\bm{+}}`

Comment: @LaRiFaRi thanks for the link but it was not directly related to my question