# ! Paragraph ended before \lst@next was complete: Using lstlisting in itemize

Tags: itemize, verbatim

I want to print a piece of verbatim within an item of an itemize environment, as below:

```
\documentclass[letter, 11pt]{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{listings}

\newcommand{\Question}[1]{{\bfseries?: #1\par\vspace{5pt}}}
\newcommand{\Answer}[1]{\noindent\ding{51}: #1}

\begin{document}

\section*{Problem \#1}
\Question{content
}

\Answer{
\begin{itemize}
    \item[1] Some content.\\
    My Verbatim:
    \begin{lstlisting}
        G = VVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVV

        PROJ = PPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPP
    \end{lstlisting}
\end{itemize}
}
\end{document}
```

But there is an error:

`! Paragraph ended before \lst@next was complete`.

I did even try the `frame` solution, presented [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36776/latex-error-when-inserting-code-listing-in-lyx), but it does still not work:

```
\documentclass[letter, 11pt]{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{listings}

\newcommand{\Question}[1]{{\bfseries?: #1\par\vspace{5pt}}}
\newcommand{\Answer}[1]{\noindent\ding{51}: #1}

\begin{document}

\section*{Problem \#1}
\Question{content
}

\Answer{
\begin{itemize}
    \item[1] Some content.\\
    My Verbatim:
    \begin{frame}[fragile]
        \begin{lstlisting}
            G = VVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVV

            PROJ = PPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPP
        \end{lstlisting}    
    \end{frame}
\end{itemize}
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Crosspost](http://latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?p=96833#p96833)

Comment: @Johannes_B: I sent that question there, because no one declared any idea, here.

Comment: Well, maybe that happened because you did not listen to helpers advice. You got two answers for the *no line to end* question, both of hem saying that an environment would be better suited for what you are trying to do. And here again, commands instead of environments.

Comment: @Johannes_B: I remember your advice within my question, considerably. The problem is that this code is a part of a big project and many people are working on that. For the sake of uniformity, we must use the commands, as they are defined, not to improve them. That is the reason behind not to applying your advice to use environment, instead of command.
Actually, I need a way to handle the problem within this `command` form. Is it possible, at all?

Comment: @Roboticist Did you ever resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there seem to be an absolute *No way* for code improvement (including a change of macros) and manually doing stuff anyways, including numbering, there is nothing much that can be done.

```
\documentclass[letter, 11pt]{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{listings}

\newcommand{\Question}[1]{{\bfseries?: #1\par\vspace{5pt}}}
\newcommand{\Answer}{\noindent\ding{51}: }

\begin{document}

\section*{Problem \#1}
\Question{content
}

\Answer{
    \begin{itemize}
        \item[1] Some content.\\
            My Verbatim:
            \begin{lstlisting}
            G =
            VVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVV

            PROJ
            =
            PPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPP
            \end{lstlisting}
    \end{itemize}
}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 20):

Not an answer to OP's question, but I got to this question when I forgot to add `[fragile]` to my frame when adding `lstlisting` code.

Example:

**Broken**

```
\begin{frame}
    \begin{lstlisting}[language=Java]
    // single line comment
    \end{lstlisting}
\end{frame}
```

**Fixed**

```
\begin{frame}[fragile]
    \begin{lstlisting}[language=Java]
    // single line comment
    \end{lstlisting}
\end{frame}
```

Answer (score 3):

The workaround with \input also worked in my case.

I encountered the same error message when trying to use lstlistings within the multiaudience package:

```
\usepackage{multiaudience}
\SetNewAudience{guests}

\begin{shownto}{guests} 
  \begin{indentcode}
        \begin{lstlisting}
         some text
        \end{lstlisting}
  \end{indentcode}
\end{shownto}

~~~~~~~   example which works   ~~~~~~~~~

\usepackage{multiaudience}
\SetNewAudience{guests}

\begin{shownto}{guests} 
  \begin{indentcode}
        \input{folder/newfile}
  \end{indentcode}
\end{shownto}

with the content of newfile.tex being saved in the 'folder':
    \begin{lstlisting}
         some text
    \end{lstlisting}
```

Comment: could you please add a fully compilable answer to check the validity? Right now, it does not fully answer this question.

Comment: Thanks. I have this issue with baposter class, moving the code out and using \input works!

Answer (score 0):

What *can* you control, here?

The issue is with a verbatim environment as the argument to a command. From [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24574/how-to-put-verb-command-inside-of-textbf-block), one solution is to use `cprotect`:

```
\documentclass[letter, 11pt]{article}
\usepackage{enumitem,cprotect}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{listings}

\newcommand{\Question}[1]{{\bfseries?: #1\par\vspace{5pt}}}
\newcommand{\Answer}[1]{\noindent\ding{51}: #1}

\begin{document}

\section*{Problem \#1}
\Question{content
}

\cprotect\Answer{
\begin{itemize}
    \item[1] Some content.\\
    My Verbatim:
        \begin{lstlisting}
            G = VVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVV

            PROJ = PPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPP
        \end{lstlisting}
\end{itemize}
}
\end{document}
```